# writefile() to file descriptor produces output with alignment issue

Tags: vim, io-redirection, file-descriptors

The command that produces weird output:

```
$ vim -ec 'call writefile(["line1","line2"],"/proc/self/fd/9") | qall!' 9>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
line1
     line2
          $
```

Same command piped to `cat` to check for terminal control sequences:

```
$ vim -ec 'call writefile(["line1","line2"],"/proc/self/fd/9") | qall!' 9>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | cat -A
line1$
      line2$
            $
```

Passing `-s` (ex silent mode) to `vim` seems to fix the problem, but I can't use this switch because I can't get syntax highlighting with this mode...

```
$ vim -esc 'call writefile(["line1","line2"],"/proc/self/fd/9") | qall!' 9>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | cat -A
line1$
line2$
$
```

Furthermore, if you pipe the output to `less` and redraw (Ctrl-L) the screen, everything aligns correctly!

After consulting the source code of Vim, I've also written a little C program to simulate what Vim does, but I could not reproduce the same behaviour with my program.

So, why we have such behaviour in this situation and how to fix it?

Comment: It's because `vim` has set your terminal to raw mode while it works - the output isn't weird at all, it just doesn't have any inserted returns. do `stty -opost` in your shell's terminal and watch what happens.

Comment: Why would you want syntax highlighting while running vim in what's essentailly batchmode?

Comment: @wurtel, I am trying to use `vim` as a syntax highlighter for `less` filter.

Comment: @cychoi OK, creative :)